# Import: module name same with file name

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, package

I have a package structure as follows (which is built by [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) using [this template](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage)):

```
project
    <package-name>
         __init__.py
         <package-name>.py
README.rst
LICENSE
setup.py
...
```

There is a class inside .py which is `Foo`

After installing it into a virtualenv with `easy_install`, I can access to the class

```
from <package-name>.<package-name> import Foo
```

I wonder how I can access `FOO` by `from <package-name> import Foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, by importing everything from `<package-name>` into the `__init__.py` file; add a line:

```
from .<package-name> import *
```

in the `__init__.py` module.

Comment: Thanks @Martjin, that's the answer.